# Can I use an image as a button in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the toggle feature in Bootstrap, but would like to replace the default buttons with an image. The image has text that reads "This week". The button right next to it will be an image that reads "All Time". Any ideas on how to do this?

You can see the webpage laid out here:
http://matthewtbrown.com/test/imageasbutton/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active thisweek">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1     (preselected)
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
</label>

</div>

rightcolumn .btn-group .btn .btn-primary .active .thisweek {
background-image: url(../images/callout.png);
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you means you want images as a radio buttons yes?

hope, this helps:

```
<style>
/*input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}*/
</style>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active thisweek">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"><img src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
</label>
```

Uncomment style to hide radio buttons graphics :)